# GridView OnItemCilck change the two images in android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm creating simple memory match game... I would like to change the images to initial image if two images are not same... how to change the specific image of grid item.My code is here.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    ImageView imageView = ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).imageView;
    imageView.setImageResource(CustomGridAdapter.mThumbSelected[i]);
    count++;
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    if (count<3){
        index.add(i);
        bitmaps.add(bitmap);
    }
    if (count == 2){
        compare(bitmaps.get(0),bitmaps.get(1));
        count =0;
        bitmaps.clear();
        index.clear();
    }
 }
 private boolean compare(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2) {
    if (b1.getWidth() == b2.getWidth() && b1.getHeight() == b2.getHeight()) {
        int[] pixels1 = new int[b1.getWidth() * b1.getHeight()];
        int[] pixels2 = new int[b2.getWidth() * b2.getHeight()];
        b1.getPixels(pixels1, 0, b1.getWidth(), 0, 0, b1.getWidth(), b1.getHeight());
        b2.getPixels(pixels2, 0, b2.getWidth(), 0, 0, b2.getWidth(), b2.getHeight());
        if (Arrays.equals(pixels1, pixels2)) {
            Log.i("valuesame","images are same");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.i("valuesame","images are not same");
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(CustomGridAdapter.mThumbSelected[i]);
like you do here... you just have to "remember" somewhere which the original image was

Comment: yeah i place original images in adapter... images are not same means i have to get that index.add(i).. this will contain two position of grid item.. now i have to change the image to that specific place... i really don't know how to do... guide me